# Force encoding in utf-8 for a php page

Tags: php, apache, encoding, utf-8, debian

I have a VPS (Debian, Apache, MySQL, PHP)

I want to force the encoding in UTF-8. I have put this line :

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset: UTF-8');
```

But the charset is still  ISO8859

I also edited the php.ini : /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
mbstring.language=UTF-8
mbstring.internal_encoding= UTF-8
mbstring.http_input=UTF-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.detect_order= auto
```

and the apache conf :

```
nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/charset
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

An iOS application is calling my php page. And I give it a JSON output. But it receives ISO charset...

Comment: When you say "the charset is still ISO8859", what do you mean?  Where do you see that value?

Comment: I look the page information (right button in Firefox) the encoding is ISO. I have a json output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your response header is incorrect:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset: UTF-8');
```

It should be:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

Notice the `=` in place of `:`

Answer (score 3):

Did you take a look at the `utf8-encode` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php ?

You may be echoing non-properly encoded text to the client. Apache does not do this for you.

Comment: Yes but when I look the page information (right button in Firefox) the encoding is ISO

Comment: Did you check if you have any warning message that could help in the error console?

Comment: Oh. Figured it. Your header is wrong, you should have `Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` instead of  `Content-type: application/json; charset: UTF-8`.

Answer (score 3):

In .htaccess file you can put:

```
php_value default_charset UTF-8
```